# Magento 2: Sorting / Filtering not work in my hardcore column of grid component

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I try to put a hardcore column **'status'** in to my product grid list.

Here is my column tag.

```
<column name="custom" class="AIS\Custom\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Seller\Course\Status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">250</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

And my column class

```
class Status extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{   
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource["data"]["items"])) {
            foreach ($dataSource["data"]["items"] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData("name");
                $item[$name] = "Completed";
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

It is success to show **"Completed"** in my grid component. However, sort the column or filter by column is not work for the column. Do I missing something need to modify ?

Comment: Hey! Any news on this? Did you manage to solve it anyhow?